# Opening an Excel workbook from SharePoint in edit mode from a Word VBA macro

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint, ms-word, office365

I am trying to open an Excel workbook in edit mode from my company's SharePoint site through a VBA macro from Word. 
I am able to open the workbook but it always opens in read-only mode with no way to even enter edit mode. Weird thing is that the ribbon that usually allows me to enter edit mode in such cases does not appear at all.

I tried adding ActiveWorkbook.LockServerFile to the created object (returns an error) and to the workbook I'm trying to open and it did not change a thing.

I also tried opening it using :
`Workbooks.Open(Filename:="\\filepath\file.xlsm", UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True)`, also did not help. Argument `False` also does not work.

I have a user form in a Word document that automatically fills input data into necessary places in the document, calculates payments and saves it as pdf. Afterwards I want to add a record to tot he bottom of the Excel file I use to keep track of the generated documents. So basically I want to open the Excel workbook and add a new line after the last row based on the data I input to the Word's userform.

No matter what I do, it always opens in read-only mode with no way to even manually enter edit mode.

I suspect that it's an issue with my company's trust center settings as everything is blocked and grayed out and I can't mess with those to see if it's the issue. Is that possible?

Comment: you said `ReadOnly:=True` but this means that you want to open the workbook in Read Only. Is that a typo ?

Comment: I tried both. I read somewhere that it might help for some reason and unfortunately it did not.

Comment: I will put some code as answer please comment it and tel me if this work for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this code from [MSDN Forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/7133c228-9f91-4118-b8cc-8cc79d44af83/intermittent-opening-sharepoint-file-from-excel-vba?forum=sharepointgeneral) open the file you just selected thanks to the dialog box ?

Please **make sure** that `https://sharepoint.com/team/folder` is the good url

```
sub tryme()
Dim SummaryWB As Workbook
Dim vrtSelectedItem As Variant

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    .InitialFileName = "https://sharepoint.com/team/folder" & "\"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Show
    For Each vrtSelectedItem In .SelectedItems
        Set SummaryWB = Workbooks.Open(vrtSelectedItem)
    Next
End With

If SummaryWB Is Nothing then Exit Sub

end sub
```

If the MSDN Code work maybe you can try this :

```
Set MyWorkBook = Workbooks.open("https://sharepoint.com/team/folder" & "\" & FileName)
```

Please **don't least** that `FileName` Can be just the name of the workbook like `test.xlsm` or the workbook name + folder like `foldername1\foldername2\test.xlsm`

As I Said in comment, I am waiting for your feedbacks to build an acceptable answer, Kindest regards

Comment: I also took this solution into consideration but I wanted to make it open a specific file with a fixed name as I am not the only user of the Word document generator and the Excel file and there is always a risk that other users will pick a wrong Excel file by accident (we have several workbooks in the same location) and save the record to a whole different workbook and it will get lost or crash the macro altogether. I will try your code at work tomorrow and come back with an answer as I believe this will be the only way to do what I want if I don't figure out how to force opening in edit mode.

Comment: @hollson I will edit this answer so if the 1st code work you will need to try the second one just under. Please don't least that even if it works I am waiting for your feedbacks. Kindest regards

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me, I will get back with an answer when I have access to the SharePoint tomorrow.

Comment: @hollson I Edited my answer, see you tomorrow !

Comment: @hollson what js going on ? :)

Comment: Sorry for late response, Dorian, I had a busy day yesterday and forgot to answer you, my apologies this is my fault. Now I have no idea what is going on but yesterday I was about to reply to you that the solution of yours doesn't work (I was constantly getting a message that the workbook is open in another application and it froze my Excel each time or Application-defined or object-defined error) but I just tried it again and now it works and the second solution of yours works too. I literally have no idea what changed, but thank you so much for your help and time. Have a great day!

Comment: @hollson glad i could help you !

Answer (score 2):

Tried a lot of solutions, the only one that successfully worked for me was the adaptation of your link to the file:

From this (as you copy it via "Copy link" in SharePoint"):

https://pmt.sharepoint.com/:x:/r/teams/ClearServiceRus/Teams%20Wiki%20Data/General/Book.xlsx?d=wc4cde03eae523df9a7082c18g4ege61b&csf=1&web=1&e=lnONME

To this (special attention to "/:x:/r" part) :

https://pmt.sharepoint.com/teams/ClearServiceRus/Teams%20Wiki%20Data/General/Book.xlsx

Code:

```
URL = "https://pmt.sharepoint.com/teams/ClearServiceRus/Teams%20Wiki%20Data/General/Book.xlsx"
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(URL)
Debug.Print wb.FullName
```